# No puedo convertir certificado crt a pem

Tags: cmd

Tengo un certificado .crt de AFIP y quiero convertirlo a .pem. Para lo mismo hago lo siguiente:

```
c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe x509 -inform der -in G:\despensa\Win32\Debug\certificado\certificado.crt -out G:\despensa\Win32\Debug\certificado\certificado.pem**
```

Pero me devuelve:

> unable to load certificate
>   7200:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:.\crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:1320:
>   7200:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:.\crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:382:Type=X509**

Que puede ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ejemplo válido, de CRT a PEM:

```
c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl x509 -in G:\despensa\Win32\Debug\certificado\certificado.crt -out 
G:\despensa\Win32\Debug\certificado\certificado.pem
```

Explicación:

Para el uso de `-inform der` tienes que tener el archivo con la extesión `.der`.

Lo que puede hacer es transformar tu `crt` a  `der` y de  `der` a  `pem`, también te pongo los pasos.

CRT a DER:

```
c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl x509 -in G:\despensa\Win32\Debug\certificado\certificado.crt -outform der -out G:\despensa\Win32\Debug\certificado\certificado.der
```

DER a PEM:

```
c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl x509 -in G:\despensa\Win32\Debug\certificado\certificado.der -inform der -out G:\despensa\Win32\Debug\certificado\certificado.pem
```